# Equality Operator not working in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have recently started working in codeigniter and I am trying data validation through jquery. I send the email entered in textbox to controller and it sends either "exist" or "notexist" in return . Now when I try to compare the result, it always goes to else in both cases. I cant understand why is it happening?
Please correct me wherever I am doing mistake , if any. Thanx in advance.

```
if (pattern.test(user_name)) {
    $.post('http://localhost/index.php/user/checkuseremail', 'user_name=' + user_name, function(datar) {           
        console.log(datar);
        if (datar.toString() === "exist") {
            alert('Email Exists');
        }
        else {
            alert('Valid email.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `datar`? It works fine if the value is set correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/mvf8sz3j/. My guess is you have some white-space around the value. Try using `$.trim`.

Comment: If the email already exists, it gets "exist" , otherwise it gets "notexist". I have logged it and it logs both values in different cases but the alert always shows "Valid Email".

Comment: can you trim the value and see `console.log(datar, datar.trim() == 'exist');`

Comment: @Massab can you show the exact response you are getting ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanx dude.... It worked using $.trim !

Comment: And Thanx everyone for quick response. :)

Comment: Do we get "Negative Vote" for asking a question here ?????

Answer (score 0):

in "localhost/index.php/user/checkuseremail":

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$output=array("result"=>"notexist");
if($username=="condition"){
$output['result']="exist";
}
die(json_encode($output));
```

in page :

```
$.post('http://localhost/index.php/user/checkuseremail', 'user_name=' + user_name, function(datar) {           
    console.log(datar);
    if (datar.result == "exist") {
        alert('Email Exists');
    }
    else {
        alert('Valid email.');
    }
},"json");
```